# How to combine "matching" levels with associated data in r?

Tags: r

The "Bacteria_phyla" column has 70 levels, but there are 24,364 rows. How can I combine the matching levels so that I have 70 phyla and the correct number of sequence reads associated with each phyla?

Example data:

```
structure(list(taxa.P = structure(c(7L, 61L, 51L, 27L, 51L, 25L, 
18L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 22L, 51L, 51L, 7L, 51L), .Label = c(" p__", 
" p__[Caldithrix]", " p__[Parvarchaeota]", " p__[Thermi]", " p__AC1", 
" p__Acidobacteria", " p__Actinobacteria", " p__AD3", " p__AncK6", 
" p__Armatimonadetes", " p__Bacteroidetes", " p__BHI80-139", 
" p__BRC1", " p__Caldithrix", " p__CD12", " p__Chlamydiae", " p__Chlorobi", 
" p__Chloroflexi", " p__Crenarchaeota", " p__Cyanobacteria", 
" p__Elusimicrobia", " p__Euryarchaeota", " p__FCPU426", " p__Fibrobacteres", 
" p__Firmicutes", " p__Fusobacteria", " p__Gemmatimonadetes", 
" p__GN02", " p__GN04", " p__GOUTA4", " p__H-178", " p__Hyd24-12", 
" p__Kazan-3B-28", " p__KSB3", " p__LCP-89", " p__LD1", " p__Lentisphaerae", 
" p__MVS-104", " p__NC10", " p__Nitrospirae", " p__NKB19", " p__OD1", 
" p__OP1", " p__OP11", " p__OP3", " p__OP8", " p__OP9", " p__PAUC34f", 
" p__Planctomycetes", " p__Poribacteria", " p__Proteobacteria", 
" p__SAR406", " p__SBR1093", " p__SC4", " p__Spirochaetes", " p__SR1", 
" p__Tenericutes", " p__TM6", " p__TM7", " p__TPD-58", " p__Verrucomicrobia", 
" p__VHS-B3-43", " p__WPS-2", " p__WS1", " p__WS2", " p__WS3", 
" p__WS5", " p__WWE1", " p__ZB3", "k__Bacteria"), class = "factor"), 
    total_phyla = c(1, 5, 65, 33, 1, 19, 13, 48, 1, 1, 1, 5, 
    3, 1, 32)), .Names = c("taxa.P", "total_phyla"), row.names = c(NA, 
15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It is not clear what the expected output is based on the input data.  If this to `sum` the total_phyla based on taxa.P, then `aggregate(total_phyla~taxa.P, df1, sum)`

Comment: We are not experts in your field. Please explain or show what you mean in data terms.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I am always open to suggestions. As a first-time asker I am still ignorant on the process. The script suggested by akrun is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.